# Question about basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

The Royden's definition of basis of a topology is exactly as the following.

> **Definition** For a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and a point $x$ in $X$, a collection of neighborhoods of $x$, $B_x$, is called a **base for the topology at $x$** provided for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a set $B$ in the collection $B_x$, for which $B \subseteq U$. A collection of open sets $B$ is called a **base for the topology $\tau$** provided it contains a base for the topology at each point.

Let us say that we have an open set $A\in \tau\setminus \{\emptyset\}$, i.e., $A$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$, and consider $\{B_n\}$ a countable basis for the topolgy.

**I want to understand why it is true that $A$ contains some $B_n$ of $\{B_n\}$.**

My attempt is: $\exists x \in A$ (by axiom of choice, since $A$ is a nonempty subset of $X$), and by the definition above $\exists \beta \subseteq \{B_n\}$ which is a base for the topology at $x$. Since $A$ is a neighboorhood of $x$, then $\exists H \in \beta: H\subseteq A$. I cannot go further than this. Maybe because I didn't understand precisely the definition above, and (as a consequence) the definitions of first countability and second countability.

Can you help me to understand what am I missing in these concepts?

Comment: You do not need the axiom of choice to choose one element from one nonempty set.  This is a common misconception.  You would need it if you needed to simultaneously choose infinitely many elements from infinitely many nonempty sets.

Comment: To better understand the definitions, it may help to look at some examples.  For instance, convince yourself that the collection of all open intervals with rational endpoints is a base for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  This proves that $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable.

Comment: $\exists x\in A$ means $A\ne \emptyset$. The Axiom of Choice is another topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that there are too many things called $B$, and the informal notation $\{B_n\}$ also seems confusing.  I'm going to use capital letters for subsets of $X$, and calligraphic letters for sets ("collections") of subsets of $X$.

Suppose then that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $(X, \tau)$ (you can think of $\mathcal{B}$ as being countable if you like, but it's irrelevant to this proof).  Since $A$ is not empty, it contains at least one point; let $x$ be such a point<sup>*</sup>.  Then since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $(X, \tau)$, by definition it has a subset $\mathcal{B}_x \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ which is a base at $x$.  By definition of a base at $x$, since $A$ is an open set containing $x$, there exists $U \in \mathcal{B}_x$ with $x \in U$ and $U \subseteq A$.  In particular, $U \in \mathcal{B}$ so we are done.

<sup>*</sup> This step does *not* require the axiom of choice.  It is an example of [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) which is valid in first-order logic without any axioms whatever.  You can use it multiple times to get any finite number of elements, if you like.  The axiom of choice is only needed when you need to choose an infinite number of elements from an infinite number of sets; you can't just use existential instantiation an infinite number of times, because a proof is only allowed to contain a finite number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

Rather more like this:   $\forall x\in A,\,\exists B_x$ such that $(~\!x\in B_x~\!)\land (~\!B_x\subset A~\!)$.

Then, further, $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}B_x$.  Thus $A$ is a union of basis elements.   This, as far as I know, is the idea of a basis (this author is calling it a "base";  either way).

Then as for *first countable*, it means each point has a countable (neighborhood) base.

And a topology is *second countable* if there is a countable basis (base) for it.

Comment: I made a small edit — I was confused about what the set $B_x\land B_x$ was for a moment. Of course, feel free to roll it back if you like.

Comment: Many authors prefer "base" and so do I. "Basis" has other meanings, e.g. in linear algebra. Using "basis" instead of "base" can get confusing when discussing topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a nonempty subset of $X$, $\exists x \in A$ (by axiom of choice, ). The definition above of basis of topology can be rephrased as  $\forall A\in \tau:\forall x\in A: \exists B_x  \in \{B_n\}: x\in B_x \subseteq A$. So $A\supseteq B_x:B_x \in \{B_n\}$. Indeed, $A$ must contain some $B_x$.

Note that a base $C$ for the topology has an element cointained not only in the neighborhoods of a single $x$, but in the neighborhoods of all $x\in X$. I think this was the key element to understand the relation between the definitions of basis for topology at a point, and basis for topology. To be honest, I didn't like the way the author presented both concepts.

Comment: No axiom of choice, as was explained by Nate above.